# SSMS doesn't capture comments in procedures, views, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, comments, procedure

My comments are not saved when I create or alter a procedure, view, etc.  Any changes to actual code are saved.

I'm running SSMS 18.5.  It seems to be server specific, meaning I can connect to DBs on other servers and the problem doesn't exist.  A peer of mine is running the same version and he does not have this issue.  I have tried reinstalling SSMS with no luck.   I've also compared scripting options and they are the same as my peer.

Is there a setting or configuration that needs adjusting?  Thanks.

Comment: Where are your comments located relative to the DDL statements in the batch?

Comment: I've tried commenting everywhere.   No comments save.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the DB was encrypted and "Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted" was enabled.

tools --> Options --> query execution --> SQL Server --> Advanced.

I disabled this and that allowed me to comment.  However, I'm not 100% sure what this does.. So I will enable until I know more.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of 3rd party add-ons that will strip comments based on the SQL instance. Do you have any add-ons installed?

Comment: Good thinking, but no 3rd party add-ons.